# Dynamically add projections to NHibernate query

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm, queryover

Trying to implement following queries in NHibernate QueryOver.

**SQL**

```
SELECT
     SUM(GrossChargeAmount)
FROM Charges
INNER JOIN Account on Account.Chargekey = Charges.Chargekey

SELECT
     SUM(GrossChargeAmount),
     Account.AccountHolder
FROM Charges
INNER JOIN Account on Account.Chargekey = Charges.Chargekey
GROUP BY
     Account.AccountHolder
```

**NHibernate:**

```
var accountAlias = null;

var baseQuery = session.QueryOver<Charges>()
                .JoinAlias(c => c.Account, () => accountAlias)
                .SelectList(s => s.SelectSum(c => c.GrossChargeAmount))
```

I have code that constructs the baseQuery. I then, depending on method parameters will want to append the *GROUP BY* to the baseQuery like:

```
baseQuery.SelectList(s => s.GroupBy(() => accountAlias.AccountHolder)
```

This however ends up resetting projections on my baseQuery and essentially "overwritting" the initial projections ( .SelectList(s => s.SelectSum(c => c.GrossChargeAmount)) ). At this stage an execution of the query will not have any SUM() bu just the GROUP BY.

**TLDR;** How do I add projections to an Nhibernate QueryOver instance?

Last, but not least I'm running on NHibernate 2.0.50727

Comment: There's no such thing as NHibernate 2.0.50727

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
baseQuery.SelectList(s => 
    s.SelectSum(c => c.GrossChargeAmount)
    .GroupBy(() => accountAlias.AccountHolder))
```

you could also build up the expression passed in to SelectList if you prefer

Comment: In the end, I ended up maintaing an IList<IProjection> that I pass into baseQuery.Select(). Thanks!